# Capture the screen image without screen capture spamming

Tags: java, image, tcp, screen, capture

Is there a way to capture the screen image without screen capture spamming?

I'm trying to get the image from my screen similar way to something like LogMeIn does or Join.Me in Java. But I can't seem to find an efficient way of doing it other than just spamming screen captures. The end goal is to be able to send these images over a TCP connection. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> like LogMeIn does or Join.Me in Java

Don't know what those applications do. Maybe [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) will do what you want. You can get an image of the desktop or any component in your Java application.

Comment: This is definitely something I'll try, it's at least cleaner than what I was originally planning on doing. Thanks much.